# Jquery Datepicker does not fire for the second time

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

So i have this code

```
$('#apply').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true, changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",

    onClose: function(selectedDate){
       $('#last').prop('disabled', false);
       $('#last').datepicker('destroy');
       var formatted = selectedDate.split('-');
       var new_date = formatted[1]+"/"+formatted[0]+"/"+formatted[2];
       $('#last').datepicker({
         dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",           
         minDate: (function(){                 
            var min = new Date(new_date); 
            min = $('#apply').datepicker('getDate');
            var newmin = new Date(new_date);
             newmin.setDate(min.getDate()+121);
            return newmin;
         })(),
         maxDate:(function(){
            var min = new Date(new_date);
             min = $('#apply').datepicker('getDate');
            var newmin = new Date(new_date);
            newmin.setDate(min.getDate()+129);
            return newmin;

         })(),

       });


    }
```

});

The problem is that my date **#apply** datepicker would not fire the second time around, (clicking the text box for the first time, the date picker will show, clicking outside and then clicking the textbox again the date picker woukd not show) why is that? can you help me?

Here is a [JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DHyPe/20/) to help you understand my problem

Thank you,

Comment: In fiddler it is working fine

Comment: @monu the first text box? its not working on me. click it first, then click outside of it then try to click it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line causes the error,

```
min = $('#apply').datepicker('getDate');
```

updated 
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DHyPe/36/)

if you are not selecting the date first. min will be null. It will causes the error in

```
newmin.setDate(min.getDate()+121);
```

Comment: can you explain to me why is that behave like that?

Answer (score 1):

You need have a null check for min since if you are not selecting any date "getdate" returns null

```
 onClose: function(selectedDate){
           $('#last').prop('disabled', false);
           $('#last').datepicker('destroy');
           var formatted = selectedDate.split('-');
           var new_date = formatted[1]+"/"+formatted[0]+"/"+formatted[2];
           $('#last').datepicker({
             dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",           
             minDate: (function(){                 
                var min = new Date(new_date); 
                min = $('#apply').datepicker('getDate');
                var newmin = new Date(new_date);
                  if(min != null)
                 newmin.setDate(min.getDate()+121);
                return newmin;
             })(),
             maxDate:(function(){
                var min = new Date(new_date);
                 min = $('#apply').datepicker('getDate');
                var newmin = new Date(new_date);
               if(min != null)
                newmin.setDate(min.getDate()+129);
                return newmin;

             })(),

           });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DHyPe/22/